# How can I know how much each user has contributed to a SVN repository?

Tags: svn

I'm trying to figure out with a friend of mine who has contributed the most to a SVN repository we both commit changes to. Is there a tool or svn command to know how much % of the total lines of code have been committed by each user?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think there is a way, but you can start writing a script by starting with "svn blame".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this :

```
svn blame SVN_FILE_PATH | gawk '{print $2}' | sort | uniq -c
```

Comment: When I tried that on a file, it works, but on a directory (basically I want this done for the whole project), it says: svn: Start revision must precede end revision

Comment: I guess I'll have to make a script if there is no easy way. Thanks!